# auto submit form when trigger/function fires

Tags: jquery, forms

I have the following working form:

```
<div id="player_won">
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
Firstname: <input type="text" name="firstname" />
Lastname: <input type="text" name="lastname" />
Score: <input type="text" name="score" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
</div>
```

When clicking submit, it will submit the data to my database. All works great. The only downside is that it will show this insert.php file after a succesfull submit.

Now I also have the following trigger:

```
function gameWon(){ 
 var $game_board = $("#game_board_container");
 var $player_won = $("#player_won");
 $player_won.show();
 $game_board = $player_won = null;
};
```

When this happens, it will show the div where the form is in. Since all the fields are already pre-filled, I also want to submit the form at the same time, automaticly, without needing to press the submit button. (but still show the form/div ofcourse)

How to do this? In addition, I also don't want to be forwarded to the insert.php file. I just want the div to pop-up when triggert, submit the form at the same time, and do nothing else (The user can close the pop-up div himself if needed).

Hope you guys can help me out!

Kind regards,
Maurice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To trigger a submit, just do `$("form").submit()` wherever you want to do a submit. To avoid going to `insert.php` file, add `return false;` at the end of the submit function.

However, for this to work you'll have to do an ajax post.

E.g.:

```
$(function(){
    $("form").submit(function(){
        $.ajax({
        //ajax post logic
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks I will play around with this and come back later

Comment: It worked, this is my final code: `<script>
 $('#form').submit(function() {
  $.ajax({   
   type: "POST",
   data: $("#form").serialize(), 
   cache: false,  
   url: "insert.php"  
  });   
  return false;
 });
</script>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$.submit` http://jqapi.com/#p=submit